# How to run Spring Project on an internal server not visible Internet server

Tags: java

I have been developing a Java Spring project expected to run on internal dedicated server for all the internal staff able to connect the project through the browser for example:

by typing the address...

```
   http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/..
```

What is the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy your application in your application server (jetty, tomcat, jboss/wildfly or whatever you're using). Then the web application would be accessible to all the PCs in the organization that are connected to the same LAN where the server is connected.

Also, the people in the organization won't access to your application through localhost, but using the host name of your server:

```
http://<server_host_name>:<port>/FirstSpringMVCProject/
```

Note that by deploying your application in an internal server, **it is not** deployed to the internet world, there are few more steps to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks @Luiggi Mendoza for the answer, Initial step to deploy the application over internal server, with your answers can achieve it, Thanks.